# SQL Query to find instances within 60 days of an earlier instance

Tags: sql

I have a table with Result Dates, Result Values and User IDs. I am looking for a way to find the people (number and specifics) that had result values greater than a number (20) that ALSO had a follow up result within 60 days of their initial result.

I have no problem getting the list of people with the result greater than 20, just don't know how to also find the people that were re-tested within 60 days and have a result.

I am very, very new to SQL, not sure what else is needed to help...thanks!!!

Comment: Which RDMS? Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server? What is the Primary Key in your table? Is `UserID` a FK?

Comment: You should be able to do this with a self-join of the table with itself. Please show what you've tried. And answer @OverMind's question -- add a tag for the RDBMS.